# offline online application architecture in java/adobe air

Tags: java, servlets, air, adobe, javafx

Recently one of my friend has asked me to design an application with feature to work both offline and online. I have been reading a bit about it online and found few options.

1. Using Adobe Air with a central web app which will be master and synced with local db(sqllite/derby).
2. Using JavaFx2 same as above.
3. A pure web based model(spring 3 mvc/jsf2) with embedded db apache derby/hsql/sqllite and servlet container Jetty for local/offline support and a master web app for online activities.

I'll really appreciate if people out there those who have done this kind of application please share their experience, how to go about such an application and what can be pros and cons of different approaches.

PS: I want to be in java or adobe stack.

Comment: In my opinion this is question is too broad to be answered here. Neverthess, you should add HTML5 + local storage to your list.

Comment: asked as few pointers would help google search :). well thanks for comment and time

Answer (score 1):

We've done somethong similar with Eclipe RCP application and mySql local database.

Technically, that was not too complex, just be careful of the perf when a big synchro starts.

The difficult point is to manage the rules around the synchronisation of the data. Best is - if you can - to have tables only sync in one way (reference data from master to local, for example).
An other good thing is to store where your data comes from for each row, this may help your sync rules.

hth